# how to fix the XSLT 3.0 maps issue?

Tags: xslt-3.0

I am taking an XML file as input which contains the employee data and the mapping values i.e. Job Family Id and Job Family Name. So when an employee has a matching Job Family Id then we are replacing the Job Family name in the Worker_Data and rest of the elements in the Worker_Data is same. So I used the Identity match and then called the element where the value needs to replace. But it is giving me the blank for the Job Family name.

I have tried the below XSLT code to create the map and called the same for the Job Family ID match. It is just giving me the blank nothing else. Not getting clearly what I am missing. If any of you can give me a hint on what is going wrong that will be really helpful for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="3.0">

    <xsl:mode streamable="no" on-no-match="shallow-skip" use- accumulators="JobFamilyLookup CurrentLookupValue" />

    <xsl:output method="xml" />

    <xsl:accumulator name="CurrentLookupValue" as="xs:string" initial- value="''" streamable="no">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="wd:JobFamilyID/text()" select="string()" />
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:accumulator name="JobFamilyLookup" as="map(xs:string,xs:string)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="no">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="wd:JobFamilyName/text()" select="map:put($value, accumulator- 
    before('CurrentLookupValue'),string(.))" />
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wd:Job_Family_ID">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="accumulator-before('JobFamilyLookup') ( 
        normalize-space( wd:Job_Family_ID ) )" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wd:JobFamilyGroupDetails">

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wd:test xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
<wd:Worker_Data>
    <wd:EmpID>50001</wd:EmpID>
    <wd:Job_Title>Global Talent Director</wd:Job_Title>
    <wd:Job_Family_ID>TAL_TALENT_ACQUISITION</wd:Job_Family_ID>
</wd:Worker_Data>
<wd:Worker_Data>
    <wd:EmpID>50000</wd:EmpID>
    <wd:Job_Title>Executive Assistant</wd:Job_Title>
    <wd:Job_Family_ID>ADMIN_EXECUTIVE_ASSISTANT</wd:Job_Family_ID>
</wd:Worker_Data>
<wd:JobFamilyGroupDetails>
    <wd:JobFamilyDetails>
        <wd:JobFamilyID>ADMIN_EXECUTIVE_ASSISTANT</wd:JobFamilyID>
        <wd:JobFamilyName>ADMIN - Executive Assistant</wd:JobFamilyName>
    </wd:JobFamilyDetails>
    <wd:JobFamilyDetails>
        <wd:JobFamilyID>TAL_TALENT_ACQUISITION</wd:JobFamilyID>
        <wd:JobFamilyName>TAL - Talent Acquisition</wd:JobFamilyName>
    </wd:JobFamilyDetails>
   </wd:JobFamilyGroupDetails>
</wd:test>
```

Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wd:test xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
<wd:Worker_Data>
    <wd:EmpID>50001</wd:EmpID>
    <wd:Job_Title>Global Talent Director</wd:Job_Title>
    <wd:Job_Family_ID>TAL - Talent Acquisition</wd:Job_Family_ID>
</wd:Worker_Data>
<wd:Worker_Data>
    <wd:EmpID>50000</wd:EmpID>
    <wd:Job_Title>Executive Assistant</wd:Job_Title>
    <wd:Job_Family_ID>ADMIN - Executive Assistant</wd:Job_Family_ID>
</wd:Worker_Data>
</wd:test>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply use a key:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:key name="details" match="JobFamilyDetails" use="JobFamilyID"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="Worker_Data/Job_Family_ID[key('details', .)]">
      <xsl:copy>{key('details', .)/JobFamilyName}</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="JobFamilyGroupDetails"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7mJ

As for your request on using streaming and accumulators, as streaming works forwards only the only way to solve that would be to store the relevant workers data in a sequence of maps and then later to capture the details data in a map as you tried to use it as a parameter in a template for each item in the sequence of the workers data map that outputs the relevant element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
    xpath-default-namespace="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip" streamable="yes" use-accumulators="#all"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:accumulator name="current-id" as="xs:string?" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="JobFamilyDetails/JobFamilyID/text()"
            select="string()"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:accumulator name="details" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="JobFamilyDetails/JobFamilyName/text()"
            select="map:put($value, accumulator-before('current-id'), string())"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:accumulator name="workers" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)*" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Worker_Data" select="$value, map { }"/>
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Worker_Data/EmpID/text()" 
            select="let $wmap := $value[last()]
            return ($value[position() lt last()], map:put($wmap, 'id', string()))"/>
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Worker_Data/Job_Title/text()" 
            select="let $wmap := $value[last()]
            return ($value[position() lt last()], map:put($wmap, 'title', string()))"/>
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Worker_Data/Job_Family_ID/text()" 
            select="let $wmap := $value[last()]
            return ($value[position() lt last()], map:put($wmap, 'jfid', string()))"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="accumulator-after('workers')" mode="output">
                <xsl:with-param name="details" select="accumulator-after('details')"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match=".[. instance of map(*)]" mode="output" expand-text="yes">
        <xsl:param name="details"/>
        <wd:Worker_Data>
            <wd:EmpID>{?id}</wd:EmpID>
            <wd:Job_Title>{?title}</wd:Job_Title>
            <wd:Job_Family_ID>{$details(?jfid)}</wd:Job_Family_ID>
        </wd:Worker_Data>      
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifpL/2

Whether that performs well in terms of memory usage I have not tested.

Comment: Thank you Martin, I want to make this code as streamabl. That is why I came to map concept in XSLT3.0. I made the Streamable as no in the above snippet, but I will turn on when I am placing the code in the application. Sorry to confuse you guys.

Comment: Streaming works forwards only so I don't see a way, given your input structure where the `JobFamilyDetails` are stored after the `Worker_Data`, to use streaming to access the details when processing the worker data. You would need to process the input twice to store the details after the first processing and have it available during the second processing of the worker data.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation Martin. I am still learning XSLT and really not aware of this Streaming working procedure. If you dont mind, will you please suggest me a book or site to learn and understand the XSLT 3.0 stuff.

Comment: Well, the StackOverflow section on XSLT 3 https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-3.0/info has lots of links to specs and material, as have the sections on XSLT in general and the XSLT 2 version https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-2.0/info which surely also helps if you are new to XSLT in general. I am not sure there is any book dedicated to XSLT 3 but Saxonica in Saxon's documentation treats about everything related to XSLT and XPath http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/xslt30.html. Another vendor, Altova, also has a section dedicated to XPath 3 https://www.altova.com/training/xpath3.

Comment: Thank you very much Martin. This will definetly help me allot.

Comment: @Raj, I have added an example using streaming and accumulators but as the details follow the worker data in the input the accumulators also need to store the worker data before being able to map to the details data.

Comment: Thank you Martin for spending your time on my query. I will definetly test this in my app and let you know the result.

Comment: I just tested tested the script and it is working as expected. Thank you Martin for your help. If you dont mind, could you give me some idea when you are having free time.